# create child extjs iframe

Tags: django, extjs

I am working with django and extjs. I create a html page in extjs iframe like that

```
items: [{
     html: '<iframe src="/page/object/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'
 }],
```

The `views.py` render the `html` page in the `iframe`

```
return render(request, 'page.html', {
    'items': item
})
```

I want to use `Ext.fly("")` add something (createchild) on the html page in the iframe.

Is it possible? how?

Comment: I see you've not accepted any answer to your questions. That kinda defeats the goal of Stack Overflow. It would be great if you could review all the questions you've asked, accept correct answers and give feedback on proposed solutions that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, all the following supposes that the IFrame is loaded from the same domain (same origin policy); but, considering your example, that seems to be the case. If you're loading your IFrame from another domain, the browser will prevent you from almost any interaction with it (you can only change the hash...).

So, first, you need to grab a reference to the IFrame **DOM element** (as opposed to Ext's Element). Then, you can get a reference to the IFrame's `document` object this way (stolen from [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129984-Ext.ux.SimpleIFrame-Simple-IFrame-component)):

```
// iframe is the DOM element
var iframeWindow = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument,
    doc = iframeWindow.document;
```

Then you can use `Ext.get(doc)` or `Ext.fly(doc)`, and work with the returned wrapper Ext Element.

Here's a complete example that defines an "iframe component", waits for its load event, and adds a child:

```
items: [{
    xtype: "component"

    // using autoEl instead of html property, so the iframe will be the `el` 
    // property of the component
    ,autoEl: {
        tag : "iframe"
        ,src: "/page/object/"
        ,frameborder: 0
    }

    // listening on the iframe's load event
    ,listeners: {
        el: {
            load: function() {
                var iframe = this.dom,
                    iframeWindow = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument,
                    docEl = Ext.fly(iframeWindow.document),
                    body = docEl.down('body'); // instance of Ext.dom.Element

                // now you can do what you want with the iframe body!
                body.createChild({tag: 'div', html: 'I am bold', style: 'font-weight: bold;'})
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to assign `Ext.fly` to a variable. Better use `docEl = Ext.get()` or work inline `Ext.fly().down()`

Comment: You're right, that produces a very dangerous variable. I did that to make all steps clear but that should be avoided in real life.